# Debugging in C++ on Mac OS

Tags: c++, debugging, error-handling

I've recently bought an Apple laptop. As a contest fanatic I downloaded Code:Blocks from the official site, since I'm trying to compete in programming in C++. Everything is working fine, except for the debugger, it won't start. Everytime I debug a message in red appears on the screen

> ERROR: You need to specify a debugger program in the debuggers's
>   settings. (For GCC compilers, it's 'gdb' (without the quotes))

I've tried to re-install the application, but nothing helped. I've tried to search the internet for simular problems and solutions, but again I didn't manage to do anything.

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: The error message is very clear to me and you can't do it? Also try Xcode.

Comment: @BryanChen I'm still stucked at the same place, I've done everything I thought would help and nothing worked. Can you be more specific with your hint? And what about Xcode?

Comment: Download XCode from the Mac App Store. It ships with clang 3that is a very good replacement to gcc, and it comes with all tools already configured.